# Linear layout align element to right

Tags: android, xml

I have a linear layout that i use for a list view with a custom adapter, it consists in an image and two text views.
My problem is that the first text view length is not always the same so i dont know how to align every second text view to the same position.

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/txtresultadocolor"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     />
```

This is my code now but the second text view always changes.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the result you are trying to achieve? It is possible to let each TextView occupy a specific percentage of horizontal space. It is also an option to make second TextView of fixed width.

Comment: Some ways to think around: 1. Calculate the width of the `TextView` based on the total width available. 2. Use `layout_weight` if that helps 3. Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` and align one `TextView` to parent start and other to parent end. 4. Use `GridLayout` or `TableLayout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give `android:layout_weight="0.3"` to the first `TextView`, which will make the second `TextView` be attached to one position and the size of the first `TextView` will increase according to the length of the text.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="TextViewd1391381231283123100"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="adfafasdfs"
    android:textColor="@color/Red"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue here is android:layout_gravity="center". The textviews are getting displayed center aligned and the display length will vary as per their text sizes and they will not be aligned to the same position.

Once you remove it and add android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" to the first textview also both textviews should become aligned to the same position in the left.

Answer (score 1):

To align a view to the right use `android:layout_gravity="right"`.